# Is it possible to declare an abstract auto-implemented property in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, c#-to-f#

I'm trying to do the following F# equivalent:

```
[C#]
public virtual int Property { get; set; }
```

But this code (and many other combinations) does not work:

```
[F#]
abstract member Id: int with get, set
default val this.Id = 123 with get, set
```

Comment: well, your first example (C#) isn't an abstract auto-property... It's a virtual auto-property

Comment: Why are you trying to make it *abstract* - that's not what the C# code does. There's a big difference between virtual and abstract.

Comment: In F# the abstract+default keywords are used to produce the same result as C#'s virtual.

Comment: Example (with backing field): 

    `[<DefaultValue>] val mutable private name: string`

    `abstract member Name:string with get, set`
    `default this.Name with get() = this.name and set v = this.name <- v`

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in the Dev11 preview.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467.aspx) on F# properties, this line in the abstract properties immediately jumps out:

> Alternatively, abstract can just mean that a property is virtual, and
>   in that case, a definition must be present in the same class.

The example syntax they give is:

```
type Base1() =
   let mutable value = 10
   abstract Property1 : int with get, set
   default this.Property1 with get() = value and set(v : int) = value <- v
```

Now I'm not overly familiar with F#, but my guess is that you could set `let mutable value = 10` to your requirement of `let mutable value = 123`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that's not an auto-implemented property. I'm trying not to use the backing field.

Comment: Auto-implemented property is a new feature (F# 3.0)

Comment: Ah, this is true. Having a read of the documentation and how it's structured, I'm not sure it's possible (as your code seems to be the likely way of doing it)